# Methods not found so i cant get Events from DB

Tags: php, symfony

Im using adesigns/calendar-bundle to create a calendar on my symfony project.
I Can't get events from the DB when i access fc-load-events, This is my entity listener :

```
class CalendarEventListener
{
    private $entityManager;


    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

    }

    public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
    {
        $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStartDatetime();
        $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEndDatetime();

        // The original request so you can get filters from the calendar
        // Use the filter in your query for example

        $request = $calendarEvent->getRequest();
        $filter = $request->get('filter');


        // load events using your custom logic here,
        // for instance, retrieving events from a repository

        $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('CMRBundle:EventEntity')
            ->createQueryBuilder('company_events')
            ->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
            ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        // $companyEvents and $companyEvent in this example
        // represent entities from your database, NOT instances of EventEntity
        // within this bundle.
        //
        // Create EventEntity instances and populate it's properties with data
        // from your own entities/database values.

        foreach($companyEvents as $companyEvent) {

            // create an event with a start/end time, or an all day event
            if ($companyEvent->getAllDayEvent() === false) {
                $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), $companyEvent->getEndDatetime());
            } else {
                $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), null, true);
            }

            //optional calendar event settings
            $eventEntity->setAllDay(true); // default is false, set to true if this is an all day event
            $eventEntity->setBgColor('#FF0000'); //set the background color of the event's label
            $eventEntity->setFgColor('#FFFFFF'); //set the foreground color of the event's label
            $eventEntity->setUrl('http://www.google.com'); // url to send user to when event label is clicked
            $eventEntity->setCssClass('my-custom-class'); // a custom class you may want to apply to event labels

            //finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
            $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get :

```
if ($companyEvent->getAllDayEvent() === false) {
$eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), $companyEvent->getEndDatetime());
} else {
$eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), null, true);
}
```

All the methods in evententity are **not found** : `getAllDayEvent(), getTitle(), getStartDatetime().

I have a public fonction getDaterdv in my entity :

(Ive changed the entity) to RDV :

```
<?php

namespace CMRBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RDV
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="r_d_v")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CMRBundle\Repository\RDVRepository")
 */
class RDV
{
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datecrea", type="datetime")
 */
private $datecrea;

/**
  * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
  */
private $published = true;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="daterdv", type="datetime")
 */
private $daterdv;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="agentname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $agentname;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="qualif", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $qualif;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="agentid", type="integer")
 */
private $agentid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $company;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="comname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $comname;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="text")
 */
private $adresse;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="text")
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telfixe", type="text")
 */
private $telfixe;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telpor", type="text")
 */
private $telpor;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tarif", type="text")
 */
private $tarif;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="support", type="text")
 */
private $support;

public function __construct()
{
$this->datecrea = new \Datetime();
$this->daterdv = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set datecrea
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datecrea
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setDatecrea($datecrea)
{
    $this->datecrea = $datecrea;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datecrea
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDatecrea()
{
    return $this->datecrea;
}

/**
 * Set daterdv
 *
 * @param \DateTime $daterdv
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setDaterdv($daterdv)
{
    $this->daterdv = $daterdv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get daterdv
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDaterdv()
{
    return $this->daterdv;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set agentid
 *
 * @param integer $agentid
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAgentid($agentid)
{
    $this->agentid = $agentid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentid
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getAgentid()
{
    return $this->agentid;
}

/**
 * Set company
 *
 * @param string $company
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setCompany($company)
{
    $this->company = $company;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get company
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->company;
}


/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set published
 *
 * @param boolean $published
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setPublished($published)
{
    $this->published = $published;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get published
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getPublished()
{
    return $this->published;
}

/**
 * Set agentname
 *
 * @param string $agentname
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAgentname($agentname)
{
    $this->agentname = $agentname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAgentname()
{
    return $this->agentname;
}

/**
 * Set adresse
 *
 * @param string $adresse
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adresse
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * Set ville
 *
 * @param string $ville
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setVille($ville)
{
    $this->ville = $ville;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ville
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVille()
{
    return $this->ville;
}

/**
 * Set telfixe
 *
 * @param string $telfixe
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTelfixe($telfixe)
{
    $this->telfixe = $telfixe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telfixe
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelfixe()
{
    return $this->telfixe;
}

/**
 * Set telpor
 *
 * @param string $telpor
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTelpor($telpor)
{
    $this->telpor = $telpor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telpor
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelpor()
{
    return $this->telpor;
}

/**
 * Set tarif
 *
 * @param string $tarif
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTarif($tarif)
{
    $this->tarif = $tarif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tarif
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTarif()
{
    return $this->tarif;
}

/**
 * Set support
 *
 * @param string $support
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setSupport($support)
{
    $this->support = $support;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get support
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSupport()
{
    return $this->support;
}

/**
 * Set horaire
 *
 * @param string $horaire
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setHoraire($horaire)
{
    $this->horaire = $horaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get horaire
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getHoraire()
{
    return $this->horaire;
}

/**
 * Set comname
 *
 * @param string $comname
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setComname($comname)
{
    $this->comname = $comname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get comname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getComname()
{
    return $this->comname;
}


/**
 * Set qualif
 *
 * @param string $qualif
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setQualif($qualif)
{
    $this->qualif = $qualif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get qualif
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQualif()
{
    return $this->qualif;
}
}
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: What is the exact error? It looks strange that you posted an error looking like PHP code

Comment: All the methods in evententity are not found : getAllDayEvent(), getTitle(), getStartDatetime()

Comment: Start with `var_dump($companyEvent)` to see what you got.

Comment: Thanks deceze for you answer but nothing change i think that i must add something in the _construct. Im using phpstorm

Comment: My advice wasn't meant to fix anything, it was meant to help us on the path to debugging this. *What do you get?!* What are you *trying* to work with?

Comment: All i get is a blank page with [ ], The events in the DB dont load. Ive checked the ajax requests they work correctly but nothing is shown.

Comment: Im trying to get events from the table, when i try to getSomething from DB php show me that all methods on the companyEvent are not found.

Comment: Are CompanyEvent and eventEntity the same entity?

Comment: Yes the same code !

Comment: This is the error i get : Attempted to call an undefined method named "getAllDayEvent" of class "CMRBundle\Entity\EventEntity".

Comment: When i do a : $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('CMRBundle:EventEntity')->findAll();
I can load the events but when i do like in the code on top i have a : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 92 near 'event_datetime': Error: Class CMRBundle\Entity\EventEntity has no field or association named event_datetime

Comment: You say same code, but is it the very same file?

Comment: No, two files with the same name

Answer (score 0):

It should be name of the entity field, but not the name of the database column specified in line

```
->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
```

so check, maybe it should be like

```
->where('company_events.eventDatetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
```

assuming that you are using camel case on your EventEntity field names using symfony coding style standards.

=============================

UPDATE

=============================

Now, when you posted your entity it is clear that it is not the one you trying to fetch from the database via repository.

```
$companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('CMRBundle:EventEntity')
        ->createQueryBuilder('company_events')
        ->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
        ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Here your entity manager retrieving "EventEntity" instances from repository with name "CMRBundle:EventEntity", but to us you showed "RDV" and "CMRBundle\Repository\RDVRepository" to which it belongs to. As far as I understand from the part of the scope you shown - when some calendar event is raised you want to obtain all "event entities" from database which are in bounds of field values set in those event object that you passes to the listener. But it's unclear whether those RDV object that you have shown represent those "event entities" that you want to get from database. For now it looks like so and code related to "CMRBundle:EventEntity" just looks like some example code that your forgot to change. So, please, try to describe us the task and its context more carefully and tell if my assumption is right or wrong.

Comment: Hello,
In my RDV Entity i have a field named 'daterdv' but when i do this i get field 'daterdv' not found : $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('CMRBundle:RDV')
            ->createQueryBuilder('events')
            ->where('events.daterdv BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')

Comment: Hi, does it public? Does it has the public method getDaterdv() in the case if it does not? Could you show us the class defention of entity your trying to retrieve from 'CMRBundle:EventEntity' repository? You could yous 'edit' to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a public fonction getDaterdv in my entity :

(Ive changed the entity) to RDV :

```
<?php

namespace CMRBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * RDV
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="r_d_v")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CMRBundle\Repository\RDVRepository")
 */
class RDV
{
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datecrea", type="datetime")
 */
private $datecrea;

/**
  * @ORM\Column(name="published", type="boolean")
  */
private $published = true;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="daterdv", type="datetime")
 */
private $daterdv;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="agentname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $agentname;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="qualif", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $qualif;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="agentid", type="integer")
 */
private $agentid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="company", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $company;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="comname", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $comname;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="text")
 */
private $adresse;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="text")
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telfixe", type="text")
 */
private $telfixe;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telpor", type="text")
 */
private $telpor;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tarif", type="text")
 */
private $tarif;

/**
 * @var text
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="support", type="text")
 */
private $support;

public function __construct()
{
$this->datecrea = new \Datetime();
$this->daterdv = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set datecrea
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datecrea
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setDatecrea($datecrea)
{
    $this->datecrea = $datecrea;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datecrea
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDatecrea()
{
    return $this->datecrea;
}

/**
 * Set daterdv
 *
 * @param \DateTime $daterdv
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setDaterdv($daterdv)
{
    $this->daterdv = $daterdv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get daterdv
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDaterdv()
{
    return $this->daterdv;
}

/**
 * Set title
 *
 * @param string $title
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get title
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

/**
 * Set agentid
 *
 * @param integer $agentid
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAgentid($agentid)
{
    $this->agentid = $agentid;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentid
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getAgentid()
{
    return $this->agentid;
}

/**
 * Set company
 *
 * @param string $company
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setCompany($company)
{
    $this->company = $company;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get company
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCompany()
{
    return $this->company;
}


/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set published
 *
 * @param boolean $published
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setPublished($published)
{
    $this->published = $published;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get published
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getPublished()
{
    return $this->published;
}

/**
 * Set agentname
 *
 * @param string $agentname
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAgentname($agentname)
{
    $this->agentname = $agentname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get agentname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAgentname()
{
    return $this->agentname;
}

/**
 * Set adresse
 *
 * @param string $adresse
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setAdresse($adresse)
{
    $this->adresse = $adresse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get adresse
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAdresse()
{
    return $this->adresse;
}

/**
 * Set ville
 *
 * @param string $ville
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setVille($ville)
{
    $this->ville = $ville;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ville
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVille()
{
    return $this->ville;
}

/**
 * Set telfixe
 *
 * @param string $telfixe
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTelfixe($telfixe)
{
    $this->telfixe = $telfixe;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telfixe
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelfixe()
{
    return $this->telfixe;
}

/**
 * Set telpor
 *
 * @param string $telpor
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTelpor($telpor)
{
    $this->telpor = $telpor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get telpor
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTelpor()
{
    return $this->telpor;
}

/**
 * Set tarif
 *
 * @param string $tarif
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setTarif($tarif)
{
    $this->tarif = $tarif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get tarif
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTarif()
{
    return $this->tarif;
}

/**
 * Set support
 *
 * @param string $support
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setSupport($support)
{
    $this->support = $support;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get support
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSupport()
{
    return $this->support;
}

/**
 * Set horaire
 *
 * @param string $horaire
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setHoraire($horaire)
{
    $this->horaire = $horaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get horaire
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getHoraire()
{
    return $this->horaire;
}

/**
 * Set comname
 *
 * @param string $comname
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setComname($comname)
{
    $this->comname = $comname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get comname
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getComname()
{
    return $this->comname;
}


/**
 * Set qualif
 *
 * @param string $qualif
 *
 * @return RDV
 */
public function setQualif($qualif)
{
    $this->qualif = $qualif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get qualif
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getQualif()
{
    return $this->qualif;
}
}
```